# Html non form data to JSON with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I know that i can serialize form data to json with jquery.serialize(), but i didn't want to use that because i dont want to use bunch of hidden fields and wrap my code into form element.

**Step 1**: I have mvc project and i built html from my model and i assigned name attributes to all elements, so i end up like this:

```
<div>
<label name="Name">BMW</label>
<label name="Year">2020</label>
<label name="Owner.Id">4</label>
<label name="Owner.Name">John</label>
<label name="Users[0].Id">1</label>
<label name="Users[0].Name">Alex</label>
<label name="Users[0].Licences[0].Id">3</label>
<label name="Users[0].Licences[0].Name">Driving</label>
<label name="Users[1].Id">2</label>
<label name="Users[1].Name">Donald</label>
</div>
```

When i post the form to the controller, the ModelBinder can read this and it works.
But again - this works when i use hidden fields and form element. And i don't want to do so.

**Step 2**: I made my own serializer, that reads all the name attributes and creates json object.
This is the result:

```
{
    "Name": "BMW",
    "Year": 2020,
    "Owner.Id" : 4,
    "Owner.Name" : "John",
    "Users[0].Id" :1,
    "Users[0].name" : "Alex",
    "Users[0].Licences[0].Id" : 3
    "Users[0].Licences[0].Name" : "Driving"
    "Users[1].Id" : 2,
    "Users[1].name" : "Donald"
}
```

**Problem**: How can i convert this result into the json object?
I want something like this:

```
{
"Name": "BMW",
"Year": 2020,
"Owner": {
    "Id" : 4,
    "Name": "John",
},
"Users":[
    {
        "Id" : 1,
        "Name" : "Alex",
        "Licences":[
            {
                "Id" : 3,
                "Name" : "Driving",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id" : 2,
        "Name" : "Donald"
    }       
]
}
```

Comment: why are you using labels? If that too much important you can also use json encode data in label in order to use it in javascript.

Comment: Your "Step 2" data is not JSON, nor is it a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create your own parser after you get object of `name-text` key-value pairs you could split those keys on dot and square brackets and then use `reduce` method to build desired structure.

```js
const result = Array
  .from($('div label'))
  .reduce((o, e) => {
    const key = e
      .getAttribute('name')
      .split(/[\[(.*?)\]|\.]/)
      .filter(Boolean)

    key.reduce((r, k, i, arr) => {
      if (!arr[i + 1]) r[k] = e.textContent;
      else if (!isNaN(+arr[i + 1])) return r[k] = r[k] || []
      else if (!isNaN(+k)) return r[k] = r[k] || {}
      return r
    }, o)

    return o;
  }, {})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label name="Name">BMW</label>
  <label name="Year">2020</label>
  <label name="Owner.Id">4</label>
  <label name="Owner.Name">John</label>
  <label name="Users[0].Id">1</label>
  <label name="Users[0].Name">Alex</label>
  <label name="Users[0].Licences[0].Id">3</label>
  <label name="Users[0].Licences[0].Name">Driving</label>
  <label name="Users[1].Id">2</label>
  <label name="Users[1].Name">Donald</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#set) helper to achieve your goal.

a very rough example after using your sterilizer you can apply set in this way

```js
const values = {
  "Name": "BMW",
  "Year": 2020,
  "Owner.Id" : 4,
  "Owner.Name" : "John",
  "Users[0].Id" :1,
  "Users[0].name" : "Alex",
  "Users[0].Licences[0].Id" : 3,
  "Users[0].Licences[0].Name" : "Driving",
  "Users[1].Id" : 2,
  "Users[1].name" : "Donald"
}

const resultObj = {};

Object.keys(values).forEach(key => {
  set(resultObj, key, values[key])
})
```

in above example we are setting the values to the `resultObj` variable.